# SSH: Connection Refused

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, centos

I have a CentOS 6.4 web server running on VirtualBox hosted on Windows Server 2012.
*The server is used only for testing.*

- CentOS is running an **Apache** web server that is fully working and **accessible**
  from internet.
- The Guest has its own **public IP address**, visible in the ifconfig.
- SSH is correctly installed, configured on **port 22** as default, and running.
- I've added to **ssh_config** only the **AllowUsers** and set  **PermitRootLogin** to no.
- I've added in **iptables** the rule -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT.
- selinux has been disabled.
- The windows firewall has a rule to forward all
- Scanning with **NMAP** the public ip of CentOS server, from internet, I get port 22 and 80 OPENED and LISTENING.

If I try to connect SSH with putty *ip_address* on port 22 I immediately receive the  **CONNECTION REFUSED** message

I've tried also to connect from the Host server but I receive the same message.

Please note that the web server on CentOS is working perfectly, so there should be no firewall problem.

Is there something else I need to configure for SSH or something I can do to debug the issue?

***UPDATE**

I'm trying to connect using **PuTTY**, with **default settings**.
I've only put the **ip address**, **port**, selected SSH as connection type, and then clicked on Open. I expect to see the **login prompt** as I get from other Ubuntu server machines.

Comment: When you ssh to CentOS from your Windows2012 server can you connect? If you connect from Windows2012, and not from the internet, then the problem is something to do with either Windows2012 itself, or your virtualbox network config

Comment: No I can't connect even from Windows server 2012. I get the same message: Connection Refused.

Comment: Can you successfully ssh to the public ip address from the linux server itself?  Have you tried disabling iptables to see if this is breaking something?   Is there a virus scanner active on your Windows 2012 instance?

Comment: @MikePennington Yes, I'm able to make a self connection using the public ip address. As first response I get: "The authenticity of host 'ip_address' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is ..... are you sure you to continue?"

Comment: Your iptables rule is "-A" which means append. If there is already a drop all rule above it, it won't be seen. Try replace it with "-I" which inserts it at beginning of table and see if that works.